# can someone explain why is the argument output is not what's expected?

Tags: javascript

why is `name` returning steve for both players?

```js
function Player(name, marker){
  this.name = name;
  this.marker = marker;
  this.sayName = function(parameter){
    console.log(parameter)
  }
}
const player1 = new Player("steve", "X");
const player2 = new Player("also steve", "O");
player1.sayName(this.name); // "steve"
player2.sayName(this.name); // "steve"
```

however when I change the code to this it returns what is expected:

```js
function Player(name, marker){
  this.name = name;
  this.marker = marker;
  this.sayName = function(){
    console.log(name)
  }
}
const player1 = new Player("steve", "X");
const player2 = new Player("also steve", "O");
player1.sayName(); // "steve"
player2.sayName(); // "also steve"
```

I know it's related to scope but I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Without additional code it would show _undefined_ twice, not `"steve"`. Just use the second example, the first one makes no sense - the name is a property, not an argument.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - In the browser environment, in loose mode, it will show the name of the window (`""` if the window doesn't have a name). No idea how the window would end up being called "steve" though. :-D

Comment: `this` at global scope in loose mode refers to the global object (`window` on browsers). So `player1.sayName(this.name)` is looking up `name` on the global object, passing it into the method, and having the method output it. On browsers, `name` is the name of the window.

Comment: You probably meant `player1.sayName(player1.name); player2.sayName(player2.name);` - not using `this.name` as an argument.

Comment: why is name = "steve"???

Comment: I didn't declare `name` ever in my code environment but it's `steve` and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling this methods:

```
player1.sayName(this.name); // "steve"
player2.sayName(this.name); // "steve"
```

you give them as argument field 'name' not from their inside scope. It is 'this' context of outer function, so you probably also got name="steve" somewhere higher in this outer scope area.

You can fix it this way:

```
function Player(name, marker){
  this.name = name;
  this.marker = marker;
  this.sayName = function() {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
const player1 = new Player("steve", "X");
const player2 = new Player("also steve", "O");
player1.sayName(); // "steve"
player2.sayName(); // "also steve"
```

Comment: why is name = "steve"??? 
I didn't declare name ever in my code environment but it's steve and I don't know why

Comment: I checked out your code in online js compiler, its outputs were both 'undefined'. So I need more parts of you project or this file to say, where is the problem

Comment: I think it's a bug. now name = "bodi" and I don't have `const name = "bodi"` in my environment. how can I send to you all my files?

Comment: github link would be nice

Comment: https://github.com/BodiAli/practice/blob/main/main.js

Comment: here you got empty string cause of your this context = window, where  window.name = ''. You can see it if you console.log(this) instead of console.log(name) at file end.